# Can't get the ribbon to appear in Outlook - addin from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, outlook, add-in, ribbon

I've created an Outlook 2010 Add-in (32 bit) using vb.net (2012).  The add-in only has a ribbon tab and a small amount of code attached - just a msgbox for each button.

I've published and installed the addin, and installed the add-in in outlook.  Restarted Outlook.  The add-in appears to be active and this persists when outlook is restarted.

The ribbon doesn't appear.

As a test, I created another Outlook 2010 ribbon that adds text to newly created emails - that one works.

I'm new to vb.net.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.

I hadn't set the RibbonType property of the ribbon to appear in the 'explorer' ribbon.  The add-in was working, but I couldn't see that until I started to reply to an email.